# Salesforce: Prevent autopopulating standard Name field

Tags: salesforce, customization, force.com

I have custom object on which there is a standard field 'Name'. The field type - text (Text(80)). It does not autopopulate, and the values ​​it can be set only through the edit page.  This field is not mandatory on the project and on the edit page, but when I create a new record of this object this field is autopopulated by Id of this record. Although it is expected that the field should be left blank.

Can I fix this strange behavior with help of some options or settings? Are there any solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so, it is either auto number or text in which case it'll be required, can not be left blank, salesforce autopopulates the record with the id in case you do not provide one and there is no setting to change that behavior (that i know of on current releases)

I'll recommend changing your requirements and at least populate the name of the record with something, a naming convention for the record on it's current stage would be helpful,

That way you can list all of your "ANONYMOUS" records and assign them into a queue so a business person can go and put the right info just to cite an example, a custom unique identifier which can be recognized by your system or an external application, but never blank

Comment: Thanks for your answer, magdiel! I didn't find standard solution for this issue, and I just decided, that I will not use this fields in my business-logic and I will create my custom fields for my needs. Also I decided change field type from text to autonumber, that allow hide this fields in related lists and on layouts.